# MODIS Imagery Orthorectification (Open Source)

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, snapping, orthorectification

I am looking for an open source free software/tool for orthorectification/Geometric terrain correction of MODIS imagery.

I have looked at ESA (European Space Agency) SNAP but this sensor type is not supported only SAR.  I have also looked at the OTB (ORFEO Toolbox by the French Space Agency) through QGIS but it also seems there are limited sensors.

How to address terrain relief correction for MODIS imagery through open source platforms?