# Terrain correction / Orthorectification with gdal

Tags: gdal, terrain, orthorectification, radar

Since [MODIS Imagery Orthorectification (Open Source)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192270) had no answer, I will try to get one here with a similar problem:

I got some raster datasets with GCPs in lat/lon, but without height information. When I use gdal to project/re-project the data, I get an offset of approx. 2km, which I think comes from terrain distortion. 
Using ESA's SNAP Toolbox, I get the results I want, but they are using the actual SRTM DEM in the background.

Is there a way to provide gdal with the raster, the GCPs and a DEM to get everything done "at once" (or in several steps)?

So far, my approach (which gives the offset) looks like this:

```
gdal_translate -gcp pix1 line1 x1 y1 -gcp pix2 line2 x2 y2 (...) input.tif output.tif
```

The data are SAR raster from ERS-1, which might have something to do with the offset due to the viewing angle of the sensor

Comment: For orthorectification I would have a try with OSSIM but it probably requires sensor models too. Offset of 2km feels rather big if the view angle is not very low and/or terrain doesn't have great variation in heights.

Comment: Since the datasets are SAR images, view angles are indeed relaitvely low and elevation differs as well, because my region of interest is at the northern edge of the Alps. I have had no experience with OSSIM whatsoever, do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Start from https://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/, see from https://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/sensors that ERS-SAR is a supported sensor. I fear that OSSIM developers are not active in gis.stackexchange but the mailing list is responsive.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I'll post here if I get any feasible results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command I use to do it all at once, plus some other helpful settings to help it run a bit quicker.  If needed, you can also specify coordinates to chip the image using the -te flag.  This command will chip the image, change the output format, and orthorectify using a DEM in a single step.  You can download SRTM here: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

```
gdalwarp -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1536 -wm 1536 -rpc -to RPC_DEM=${DEM_FILE} -of GTiff -te ${aoi_coords} ${inFile} ${outFile}
```

Comment: is it possible to reproject the image without using DEM?